# Matplotlib differences in behavior of clf

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Depending on whether the clear figure function clf() is called directly from pyplot or via an instance of the Figure module it appears to behave differently.  I'm running the following script in Python 3.6 using an IPython console and Spyder.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = x**2 + 2*x + 5
#y = x**2 + 3*x + 6

# behaviour i want
plt.figure("Good Figure")
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x, y)

# behaviour i do not want
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, num="Bad Figure")
#fig.clf()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

The graphs output to a window.  The first time I run the script both graphs produce the same behavior and create the graph I want.  If I change the arithmetic used to generate `y` and simply rerun the script from the same IPython console the first plot updates correctly, it is cleared then re-plotted with the new data.  The second plot over writes what is currently display and becomes unreadable.  Using `fig.clf()` to generate the second graph, which is currently commented out, I get blank figure window.  How do I get the second graph to clear then re-plot with new data after each run?

Answer (score 1):

Put a plt.clf() above the creation of fig and ax.

The following code produces the appropriate plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = x**2 + 2*x + 5
y2 = -x**2 + -2*x + 5
#y = x**2 + 3*x + 6

# behaviour i want
plt.figure("Good Figure")
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('out1.png')
# behaviour i do not want
plt.clf()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, num="Bad Figure")
#fig.clf()

ax.plot(x, y2)

plt.savefig('out2.png')
```

Comment: When I try that it clears the good figure and has no impact on the bad figure.

Comment: I added the code I ran, produced exactly the right plots. I haven't used spyder in a long time but perhaps there is an issue with the way it loads the plots, see if saving them gives a different result.